# double nested array of object es6 filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to filter out a nested array of objects but stuck at the filter part.

How to remove one of the mark?

```
this.state = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Main",
      subs: [
        {
          id: "jay",
          name: "Jay",
          mark: [
            {
              id: "5a5d84b94a074c49ef2d4553",
              name: 100
            },
            {
              id: "5a5d84b94a074119ef2d4553",
              name: 70
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/p39momxzp7

I try to use es6 as it's more readable.

expected output

```
data: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Main",
    subs: [
      {
        id: "jay",
        name: "Jay",
        mark: [
          {
            id: "5a5d84b94a074119ef2d4553",
            name: 70
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: So, the final output should have only the first mark? Please share exact expected output along with your attempt.

Comment: @gurvinder372 done, updated my answer.

Comment: you need to filter the data by some `id` ?

Comment: @Sagivb.g check the demo? I pass in sub_id and mark_id

Comment: i don't see any of it in your demo. just paste it here in the question

Comment: do you want to keep the structure, but without the wanted part, or do you want to get a copy without the unwanted part?

Comment: @NinaScholz keep the structure of course, otherwise it would be very easy for me to remove the product by id.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are multiple nested arrays in your data structure, you need to use `forEach` those many times

```
data.forEach( s =>  //iterate data
      s.subs.forEach( t => //iterate subs
         ( t.mark = t.mark.slice( 1, 2 ) ) ) ); //slice the second value out
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Main",
  subs: [{
    id: "jay",
    name: "Jay",
    mark: [{
        id: "5a5d84b94a074c49ef2d4553",
        name: 100
      },
      {
        id: "5a5d84b94a074119ef2d4553",
        name: 70
      }
    ]
  }]
}];
data.forEach(s => s.subs.forEach(t => (t.mark = t.mark.slice(1,2))));
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4))
```

In case the **last value should be picked**?

```
data.forEach( s =>  //iterate data
      s.subs.forEach( t => //iterate subs
         ( t.mark = t.mark.slice( -1 ) ) ) ); //slice the last value out
```

Comment: slice won't work, I want to filter using the id. Can you check this demo? https://codesandbox.io/s/p39momxzp7

Comment: @SharonChai filter what using `id`? Your original question says *How to remove one of the mark?* You didn't mentioned the details of filtering. You need to use `filter` and make an attempt yourself.

Comment: @gurviner you didn't see the demo?

Comment: @SharonChai It is not loading in my network/machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter a relevant `mark` by a given `id`,
you can combine [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve it:

Note that i'm also using the [Object Rest/Spread Properties proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) (stage 4)

Running example

```js
const state = {
  data: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Main",
    subs: [{
      id: "jay",
      name: "Jay",
      mark: [{
        id: "5a5d84b94a074c49ef2d4553",
        name: 100
      }, {
        id: "5a5d84b94a074119ef2d4553",
        name: 70
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

const mark_id = '5a5d84b94a074119ef2d4553';

const nextState = {
  ...state,
  data: state.data.map(obj => {
    const filteredSubs = obj.subs.map(sub => {
      const markById = sub.mark.filter(m => m.id === mark_id);
      return {
        ...sub,
        mark: markById
      }
    });
    return {
      ...obj,
      subs: filteredSubs
    }
  })
};

console.log(nextState);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use lodash which contains many methods that can be handled easily.

Check if this is what you are looking for. (there is a good scope to refactor it but before that would like to understand if thats what you are looking for)

Below is the code that has been used there.

```
let inputId = "5a5d84b94a074c49ef2d4553";
    let filteredData =_.each(_.cloneDeep(data), function(value, key1) {
      _.each(value.subs, function(valueSubs, key2) {
        var finalSubMark = _.find(valueSubs.mark, function(eachMark) {
          return eachMark.id == inputId;
        });
        _.set(valueSubs, "mark", finalSubMark);
      });
    });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/v065w05rly

Comment: I prefer es6 without mutation or temporary variables.

Comment: base on id. You can see I pass an id in my demo https://codesandbox.io/s/p39momxzp7

Comment: From the link you provided(atleast from code) I dont see you pass Id anywhere. You just have Id properties in your JSON data. Am I missing something here?